# Subject.onNext/ onComplete does not run subscribeOn thread

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am stuck with a very annoying issue. I want to create an Observable that emits some values **after** the initialization of some component. The problem is that the other component behaves strange and calls back on the main thread.

```
strangeComponent.init(Callback)
```

its callback can be an error or success:

```
interface Callback {
   fun onError()
   fun onSuccess()  <-- this is always called on the main thread
}
```

Now I want to create an Observable that will only run once the init call was done:

```
val initSubject = CompletableSubject.create()

<T> fun withInit(call : (ObservableEmitter<T>) -> Unit) =
initSubject
  .doOnSubscribe { startInit() }
  .andThen(Observable.create{ emitter -> 
     call(emitter) 
  })

fun startInit() {
   if (!initSubject.hasComplete()) {
     strangeComponent.init(object : Callback {
        override fun onSuccess() {
          // will be called from the main thread
          initSubject.onComplete()
        }

        ...
     }
   }
}
```

And I use this like:

```
withInit {
  //---- heavy code ------
  it.onNext("Hallo")
  it.onNext("World")
  //---------
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe {
   log("received $it")
 }
```

So it turns out that the  *heavy code* part is always called from the **main**
thread instead of the **computation** thread. How do I access the given subscribeOn schedular and how do I wrap a callback so that its thread model does not affect the observable chain?

I tried all kind of constructs including `serialized` and `AsyncSubject` etc to
fix this but it is always consistent.

Comment: Apply the `subscribeOn` to the `Observable.create` directly.

Comment: Yes this works. But: It would change the API so that I would need to pass the schedular to the withInit call
`withInit(call : (ObservableEmitter<T>) -> Unit, schedular : Schedular)` and by that I can not transparantly use this in a later client code.

So my API would need to change from:

`MyApi.doSomething().subscribeOn(io()).observeOn(main())`

to

`MyApi.doSomething(io()).subscribeOn(io()).observeOn(main())`

Comment: You can't affect the scheduler the `create` uses from the outside because of `andThen`, which switches to it on the main thread because of `onSuccess` running there. You have to inject the scheduler if you want cusomization.

Comment: @akarnokd yes this is my observation as well. But it is strange, because it means that whoever calls onComplete() will fuck up the thread that I expected the heavy code is running on. This is a pretty unsatisfying implementation from RX perspective.

Comment: Rx is declarative, you have to specify what to do, plus the location of operators do matter. Who else would be using this peculiar initialization scheme?